# Stopping two intervals from running at same time

Tags: javascript, intervals

Im working on a countdown timer, this takes a dynamic unix stamp and applies it to some javascript on page to show a countdown (using a simple interval function).

Ive set up a get request to send every 10 seconds or so to check for new data, if new data exists the current countdown interval should be stopped and a new one started with the new data. Ive set up a variable to "base" this value on page load so I can detect when the value changes and start a new interval when it does.

At the moment, every time it recieves new data a new interval starts so the figures just start flashing on screen.

I cant figure out why its doing this, any ideas?

```
// main function for checking for new data every 10 seconds 

zIntervalActive = false; // for checking if interval is active or not
  function zTime() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            data: "q=" + baseTime,
            url: 'clockcalculator3.php',
            success: function(results) {
                var futureUnix = Number(results);
                console.log(results + typeof(results));
                console.log(futureUnix);
                if (futureBase == futureUnix) {
                    if (zIntervalActive === false) {
                        var zTimeInterval = setInterval(function() {MModeTimer(futureUnix)}, 1000);

                }
                    else {

                    }
                }

                else {
                    clearInterval(zTimeInterval);
                    zIntervalActive = false;
                    futureBase = futureUnix;
                    var zTimeInterval = setInterval(function() {MModeTimer(futureUnix)}, 1000);

                }


            },
            complete: function(data) {

                setTimeout(zTime, interval);
            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
    }

 //   function to "base" the value initially on page load

function zTimeStart() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            data: "q=" + baseTime,
            url: 'clockcalculator3.php',
            success: function(results) {
                futureBase = Number(results);
                console.log("ztime start" + results + typeof(results));
                console.log("ztime start" + futureBase);
            },                
            error: function() {

            }
        });
    }

 //   clock countdown function (fired as an interval)

function MModeTimer(futureDate) {
zIntervalActive = true;  
var currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var timeRemaining = futureDate - currentTime;
var minute = 60;
var hour = 60 * 60;
var day = 60 * 60 * 24;
var zDays = Math.floor(timeRemaining / day);
var zHours = Math.floor((timeRemaining - zDays * day) / hour);
var zMinutes = Math.floor((timeRemaining - zDays * day - zHours * hour) / minute);
var zSeconds = Math.floor((timeRemaining - zDays * day - zHours * hour - zMinutes * minute));

if (zSeconds <= 0 && zMinutes <= 0) {
    console.log("timer in negative");

clearInterval(zTimeInterval);


} else {

if (futureDate > currentTime) {
     $(".zdays").html(zDays);
                $(".zhours").html(zHours);
                $(".zminutes").html(zMinutes);
                $(".zseconds").html(zSeconds);

}

    }


}
```

Comment: Try putting zTimeInterval at the top, so you'd have var zTimeInterval, zIntervalActive = false; function zTime() {...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zInterval` needs to be defined in a higher level scope where it can last during your interval.  Right now, it's inside a local function and it goes out of scope and is garbage collected before you need it.

Since I can't see the whole scope of your code here, my guess would be to put it outside of the `zTime()` declaration right after this:

```
zIntervalActive = false;
var zInterval;
```

And, then remove the `var` from zInterval when you assign it so you are using the previously defined variable, not redefining a new local variable:

```
zTimeInterval = setInterval(...);
```

Comment: sorry do you mean I should declare zTimeInterval as an empty variable outside of a function? Not sure which one you meant by zInterval.. ive got a lot of variables which are variants of Z and interval. (my naming conventions need some work!)

Comment: It worked! fantastic! I just declared zTimeInterval as an empty variable and removed var when i was using it again. I know its a bit cheeky but would you mind breaking down a little why this worked for my own benefit... Im a real novice and variable scope is still something im struggling a little with. If not no worries, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Ash - It's called "variable scope".  A variable declared with `var` is defined within the current function context and can only be accessed within that context.  A new copy of that variable is created everytime the containing function is executed.  So, if you want a variable to persist across multiple executions of a function, then the variable must be declared outside that function in a scope that lasts for your duration.  The top most scope is the global scope which lasts forever, but since you can have functions within functions, the scope can more than one level deep.